# Why aren't new connection strings in Web.config file retrieved?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-config

In my ASP.NET project I added a new connection string in the Web.config file having the name "**Proba**":

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Users" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Registratura;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=REGDATABASE;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Proba" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=AnotherReg;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This piece of code should list all the 3 connection strings:

```
List<String> conns = new List<string>();
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings conn in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{          
         if(conn.Name != "LocalSqlServer")      
                    conns.Add(conn.Name);
}
```

But it only detects the former 2 strings. I have built and rebuilt, closed Visual Studio and then reopened it, but nothing changed.

I have also tried to update the database in the Package Manager Console, but once again the connection is not found and the following red error occurs:

> No connection string named 'Proba' could be found in the application
>   config file.

Why could it happen?

Comment: Silly question, but sometimes it the little things - are you sure you updated the correct web.config file?  Have you tried restarting IIS (or IIS Express) to ensure the changes are picked up?  You shouldn't need to restart them, but it wouldn't hurt if you're not seeing them and everything else looks correct.

Comment: Of course I have also done that. But it's not the problem.

Comment: As per the code you have their should be no issue to use the connection string. You can try by calling each string individually  for more info about the issue

Comment: What do you mean by 'calling', @RahulHendawe?

Comment: Like - `string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Proba"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: Where is the web.config? In the top root of your project? Do you have any transormations being run?

Comment: @RahulHendawe, I did that too.

Comment: @mason, yes, it is in the top root. The transform file is for the Release configuration, but Debug is my active configuration now.

Comment: So, did you able to use `Proba` connectionstring or same result?

Comment: Same result, @RahulHendawe.

Comment: I guess you need to add a reference to the System.Configuration assembly if that have not already been added.

Comment: Oh no, of course I have that reference!!! It's a different problem and I cannot catch it...

Comment: when you build, and look in the bin directory for your project, and open up the web config, do you see 2 connection strings or 3? 

If it's 2, you know the problem is not with the code that reads connection strings...it's probably in a transform or you're editing the wrong web config.

(Hint, it's not the code above that reads your connection strings, thats all good)

Comment: Oh my, that was silly indeed... I don't know which Web.config that was, because it was identical to the right one. Anyway, I double clicked the correct Web.config and another window showed up with only 2 strings. The one I had modified still had 3 strings, but it was probably too old opened up there, previously to some changes, so it didn't make any difference. Now it's all over. Thank you, @SteveG!

Answer (score 0):

After different attempts, I came to realize that the Web.config file onto which I had imprinted the new connection strings was kind of a phantom of the real Web.config that needed to be changed. It had been opened before some configuration settings I made, so it was no more available. That is why the code written in it was not considered.